# undefined local variable or method `client_house_path' for ClientHelper:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a route file with this entry:

```
 #routes.rb
get 'clienthouse', to: 'clients#house', as: :client_house
```

and one of my helper files `client_helper`, I call the path to the previous route in one of the action.

```
#client_helper.rb
def client_house
  client_house_path
end
```

I could not see the page until I have added

```
#client_helper.rb
class << self
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

to my `client_helper` file. But later when I started writing the integration test, I started to have this problem on the test suit. The test do not run as complain about not finding the variable `client_house_path`

How come the integration tests are unable to find the `client_house_path` method.

I have tried to include the helper file in the integration tests `include ClientHelper` as well as including

```
#integration/client_test
class << self
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

But did not succeed.

Comment: where are your `client_helper`?

Comment: in the helpers folder `app/helpers`.